# VSCode specify type definitions on window scope

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, definitelytyped, typed

I am trying to provide typescript type definitions for a library built with webpack that registers itself in the global window scope.
The library is built for direct integration into the browser via CDN.

I read, that defining a `Window` interface and adding the library to it should do the trick and the IDE should merge my definition with its global `Window` definition.
This works if I integrate the `*.d.ts` file as a library in WebStrom but it doesn't work with VSCode.

Here is a simple example: `my-lib.d.ts`

```
export interface Window {
    mylib: MyLib
}
export class MyLib {
    foo(): string;
    bar: number;
}
```

and the way I would like to access it: `consuming-script.js`

```
/// <reference path="my-lib.d.ts"/>
const result = window.mylib.foo();
```

While the import reference works, (I can access the `MyLib` class) IntelliSense doesn't show the additional property `mylib` on the `window` object.

Using a global declaration in the `my-lib.d.ts` works, however this makes `mylib` available under the global scope and not the `window` object which is no alternative.

What am I doing wrong? Is there something I have to change in the visual studio code settings? - I can't believe that it's so easy in WebStorm and such a hassle in VSCode which actually is a Microsoft IDE importing a Microsoft TS Type Definition.

Comment: If you use `export` in your `d.ts` it will be considered a module. Try without the `export` or if you have imports use `declare global { interface Windows { ... }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Titian Cernicova-Dragomir was right, the important part is defining the interface in the global scope.

once changed to this it worked:

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        mylib: MyLib
    }
}
export class MyLib {
    foo(): string;
    bar: number;
}
```